# Syntax for ap.add_argument()

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am new to OpenCV. I am using anaconda spyder console to write Python code. I took code form here (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/)
The code was that I am struck at is:

```
# USAGE
# python transform_example.py --image images/example_01.png --coords "[(73, 239), (356, 117), (475, 265), (187, 443)]"
# python transform_example.py --image images/example_02.png --coords "[(101, 185), (393, 151), (479, 323), (187, 441)]"
# python transform_example.py --image images/example_03.png --coords "[(63, 242), (291, 110), (361, 252), (78, 386)]"

# import the necessary packages
from pyimagesearch.transform import four_point_transform
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help = "path to the image file")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--coords",
    help = "comma seperated list of source points")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image and grab the source coordinates (i.e. the list of
# of (x, y) points)
# NOTE: using the 'eval' function is bad form, but for this example
# let's just roll with it -- in future posts I'll show you how to
# automatically determine the coordinates without pre-supplying them
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
pts = np.array(eval(args["coords"]), dtype = "float32")

# apply the four point tranform to obtain a "birds eye view" of
# the image
warped = four_point_transform(image, pts)

# show the original and warped images
cv2.imshow("Original", image)
cv2.imshow("Warped", warped)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

At line no. 13 - 17 can someone tell exactly what is happening. I know that I need to get image, get coordinates of paper (and these lines are for this purpose) but I can't get image file.

Comment: You have to run the code on a terminal `python filename.py image_path coordinates`

Comment: When I tried:
python transform_example.py images/example_01.png "[(73, 239), (356, 117), (475, 265), (187, 443)]"
It gave me error "invalid syntax"

Comment: The arguments need to be prefixed with the option name. Try `python transform_example.py --image images/example_01.png --coords "[(73, 239), (356, 117), (475, 265), (187, 443)]"`. More info about argparse here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the link provided, the arguments are parsed using **optional arguments**, i.e. arguments must be preceded with the string mentioned in `add_argument()`.

So in your case you have:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help = "path to the image file")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--coords", help = "comma seperated list of source points")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Notice `"--image"` and `"--coords"`. These are optional arguments and these strings must be mentioned before you execute the code in the terminal.

So type this on the terminal:

```
python transform_example.py --image images/example_01.png --coords "[(73, 239), (356, 117), (475, 265), (187, 443)]"
```

See [THIS PAGE](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/argparse.html) for more details on argument parsing and their various ways.